# Invalid Integer (UNIX Timestamp) Returned By Stripe

Tags: post, stripe-payments, unix-timestamp, zapier

My app is sending a POST request to stripe's API for a usage update. The Body is as follows:

`quantity=2&timestamp=1614916656`

However, the issue is Stripe returns the following error: `parameter_invalid_integer - timestamp`

I can't figure out why this is. The timestamp is the current date and time in EST converted from UTC.

[image]

Comment: How are you sending the request to Stripe? It looks like whatever module/library you're using is erroneously adding a new line character.

Comment: It's through Zapier and that's exactly what's happening. It's just a simple POST request to the Stripe API from a custom request in Zapier.

Comment: The `\n` at the end of the timestamp makes it a string, not an integer. Can you add a screenshot of how this data is being fed into stripe? is it mapped from a different step or added manually or anything? Or is it internal to Zapier and you don't create it yourself?